# Retrieving the row values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which have two columns

```
countries                       data
United states of america(USA)    1
india13                          2
```

i want to get the data from row in this format

```
countries                       data
United states of america        1
india                           2
```

in short,i want to filter index by paranthesis and number .if it contains either of this then i want to remove the parenthesis and number from row label.how i can do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use str.extract, the regex extract all alphabets from the string till it encounters parenthesis

```
df.countries = df.countries.str.extract('([A-Za-z ]+)\(?', expand = False)

    countries                   data
0   Unites states of america    1
1   india                       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.replace` in order to remove both digits and parenthesis along with text within them:

```
df.loc[:,'countries'] = df.countries.str.replace(r'[0-9]|\(.*\)','', regex=True)

            countries         data
0  Unites states of america     1
1                     india     2
```